# Repeater Control in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, repeater

Please help me to display images from database to webpage. This is my source code, but it shows error creating repeater control

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server"  OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand ="Repeater1_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="myImage" ImageUrl='<%# "~/ImageHandler.ashx?BImID="+Eval("img_id") %>'  runat="server" alt=" " ;style="height:200px;width:200px;border:1px solid gray"/><asp:Literal ID="litSeparator" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: What's the error?  Does it mention a specific control?

Comment: Also, where's your data source?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in this "ImageUrl='<%# "~/ImageHandler.ashx?BImID="+Eval("img_id") %>'".

Try to reorganize yor code like this:

```
ImageUrl='<%# GetImageUrl(Eval("img_id")) %>'
```

and then in code behind define the method GetImageUrl like this:

```
protected string GetImageUrl(object id)
{
    return "~/ImageHandler.ashx?BImID=" + id;
}
```

Regards,

Uroš